# Stalled / Stuck Task (GeneratePendingTransforms)

Tags: tasks

I’ve got a task running called “GeneratePendingTransforms”, but it seems to stop/get stuck just over 65% of the way through and never completes. Is there anything that could cause this

I’ve got Task Manager plugin (https://github.com/boboldehampsink/taskmanager - Which is amazing) installed to see whats happening and tried restarting the task multiple times but it gets stuck at the same point every time.

It gets stuck on Step 121 of 205.

Any ideas how I could debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a support article about stuck tasks.

In your case I would take a look at your logs, especially the phplog. 
You find them at: yourdomain.com/cp-path/utils/logs

https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks

Comment: Changing php.ini settings (memory limit, max execution time) worked for me.